# ECS service update timeout intermittently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

We are deploying ECS service using cloudformation from Jenkins.

Service is getting deployed successfully most of the time but sometimes it fails with timeout error.

When i logged in EC2 of ECS and tried to check the container i can see old container only and no new containers tried to get created.

In events i can see "unable to consistently start task successfully"

I have no pointers to check why sometime it takes so long to update the service and eventually get timeout.